# dispatch_sync() always execute block in main thread

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, cocoa-touch, grand-central-dispatch

Is there  any difference between if dispatch_sync is called in 3 different queue like

1.

```
 dispatch_sync(dispatch_get_main_queue(),^(void){
      NSLog(@"this execute in main thread") // via [NSThread isMainThread]   

  });
```

2.

```
dispatch_sync(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_HIGH, 0), ^(void){
    NSLog(@"this also execute in main thread")  // via [NSThread isMainThread]
}
```

3.

```
dispatch_queue_t queue;
queue = dispatch_queue_create("com.example.MyQueue", NULL);
dispatch_sync(queue, ^(void){
    NSLog(@"this also execute in main thread")  // via [NSThread isMainThread]
}
```

Whenever i call dispatch_sync, block executed in main thread, without considering in which queue it is dispatched. So why this function take queue as a argument as it doesn't use it. Can someone please clarify this?

Comment: How do you know it's executed in the main thread?

Comment: [NSThread isMainThread] says it's main thread.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`dispatch_sync` is a *blocking operation*.  That is, the function will not return until the work represented in the block is completed.

When dispatched to an *asynchronous queue* -- like one of the global queues or a concurrent queue of your own making -- there is no reason to do anything but invoke the block on the thread that called `dispatch_sync()`.   Even in the case of invoking the block on a synchronous queue, the `dispatch_sync()` is going to wait until completion anyway so, internally, it might as well stop until the rest of the work is done in the queue and then execute the block directly.

As it turns out, passing data from thread A to thread B is expensive.   If the queue is in the state where execution can happen immediately, then `dispatch_sync` will fast path the execution by simply calling the block on the thread that `dispatch_sync` was called on.

And, by definition, you shouldn't care.   The calling thread is blocked -- can't do a thing -- until `dispatch_sync()` returns.

So, really, all of this is an implementation detail.   GCD is free to execute the blocks on whatever threads it deems most appropriate.  It just so happens that *don't context switch* is often the most important rule of figuring that out.

Answer (score 8):

See `dispatch_sync` documentation, which notes

> As an optimization, this function invokes the block on the current thread when possible.

If you dispatch something synchronously, since the thread must wait for the dispatched code to complete, anyway, it will frequently run that code on the current thread. So if dispatched synchronously from the main thread, it will run on main thread. If dispatched synchronously from a background thread, it will run on that background thread.

As noted by ipmcc, a well-known exception is when a background thread dispatches something synchronously to the main thread. As the libdispatch source says:

> It's preferred to execute synchronous blocks on the current thread
>   due to thread-local side effects, garbage collection, etc. However,
>   blocks submitted to the main thread MUST be run on the main thread.

Comment: is there any case/example where this function invokes the block in background thread rather than main thread?

Comment: Yes, I'm sure there are. But in many trivial examples, when you say "I want the current thread to wait while I do something else on another thread", the compiler can cleverly conclude "why bother creating another thread if the first thread is going to sit there and wait, anyway."

Comment: I found the case where this function invokes the block in background thread. If i call dispatch_sync() in background thread, it no longer invoke block in main thread. So The thing matter- from which thread dispatch_sync is called, this function first try to invoke the block in caller thread(current thread), if not possible then may create new thread.

Comment: It doesn't matter which thread `dispatch_sync` is called on. If libdispatch *can* execute the block on the current/calling thread it will. The cases where it *can't* execute on the current/calling thread will be cases when the queue has a target, and that target has thread affinity (i.e. calling `dispatch_sync(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ...)` from a background thread -- which you should never do, because of the potential for deadlocks). There may be other cases, but IME, the cases of `dispatch_sync` executing the block on the calling thread is the *vast majority* of the common cases.

Comment: Infact, i executed dispatch_sync(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_HIGH, 0), ^(void){} in the background thread, not dispatch_sync(dispatch_get_main_queue(),so in this case it doesn't execute in main thread,execute in the background thread which is expected behavior. But if i call it in main thread then it execute it main thread. that what i wanted to mention in my previous comment.

Comment: Not sure what will happen if i call dispatch_sync(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ...) in background thread. you are right in this case i think, perhaps it will create deadlock. Thanks for your comment.I have upvoted your comment.

Comment: @russell As you can imagine, it will deadlock if you dispatch synchronously from main queue to background queue and then, within that background thread, dispatch synchronously back to main queue. Otherwise, no deadlock. (But it's pretty rare that you'd want to `dispatch_sync` to the main queue, anyway.)

Comment: @Rob, Thanks it clarifies the thing.Thanks for your answer & comment. I have upvoted both.

Comment: @Rob `dispatch_sync` from BG to MT: I see it *all the time* here on SO. Drives me nuts. Have seen it cause real-world deadlocks many times. Also, MT > BG > MT is not the *only* case where this can deadlock. If the MT is blocked waiting for any BG operation and the thread pool is exhausted, and a BG thread `dispatch_sync`s to MT, the result is the same. I think technically it'd be a "livelock", but the effect is the same; you're dead in the water.

Answer (score 0):

For your problem: you call the dispatch_sync always in main queue, and if you wanna know why, see the following:

At first you need to pay attention to the description on of "dispatch_sync"

> Submits a block to a dispatch queue for synchronous execution. Unlike dispatch_async,
>    this function does not return until the block has finished.
>    Calling this function and targeting the current QUEUE(NOT THREAD) results in deadlock.

```
#define logStep(step,queue) NSLog(@"step: %d at thread: %@ in -- queue: %s",step,[NSThread currentThread],dispatch_queue_get_label(queue));
// call the method in main thread within viewDidLoad or viewWillAppear ...
- (void)testDispatchSync{
    //let's distinctly tell the 4 queues we often use at first
    self.concurrentQ = dispatch_queue_create("com.shared.concurrent", DISPATCH_QUEUE_CONCURRENT);
    self.serialQ = dispatch_queue_create("com.shared.serial", DISPATCH_QUEUE_SERIAL);
    dispatch_queue_t mainQ = dispatch_get_main_queue();
    dispatch_queue_t globalQ = dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0);

    logStep(1,mainQ) //we're in main thread and main queue, current queue IS main queue

    // do a sync in main thread & concurrent queue
    dispatch_sync(_concurrentQ, ^{
        logStep(2,_concurrentQ)
    });

    // do a sync in main thread & serial queue
    dispatch_sync(_serialQ, ^{
        logStep(3,_serialQ)
    });

    //uncommenting the following code that you'wll see a crash will occur,  because current queue is main queue
    //    dispatch_sync(mainQ, ^{
    //        logStep(4, mainQ)
    //    });

    dispatch_async(_concurrentQ, ^{
        // inside of the this scope, current queue is "_concurrentQ"
        logStep(11,_concurrentQ)

        // using sync in any queue here will be safe!
        dispatch_sync(_concurrentQ, ^{
            logStep(12,_concurrentQ)
        });
        dispatch_sync(_serialQ, ^{
            logStep(13,_concurrentQ)
        });
        dispatch_sync(mainQ, ^{
            logStep(14,mainQ)
        });
        dispatch_sync(globalQ, ^{
            logStep(15,globalQ)

        });

        // using async in any queue here will be safe!
        dispatch_async(_concurrentQ, ^{
            logStep(111,_concurrentQ)
        });
        dispatch_async(_serialQ, ^{
            logStep(112,_concurrentQ)
        });
        dispatch_async(mainQ, ^{
            logStep(113,mainQ)
        });
        dispatch_async(globalQ, ^{
            logStep(114,globalQ)
        });

    });


    dispatch_async(_serialQ, ^{
        // inside of the this scope, current queue is "_serialQ"
        logStep(21,_serialQ)

        // using async in any queue except current queue here will be safe!
        dispatch_sync(_concurrentQ, ^{
            logStep(22,_concurrentQ)
        });
        dispatch_sync(mainQ, ^{
            logStep(23,mainQ)
        });
        dispatch_sync(globalQ, ^{
            logStep(24,globalQ)
        });

        //uncommenting the following code that you'wll see a crash will occur,  because current queue is "_serialQ"
        //        dispatch_sync(_serialQ, ^{ //app will die at here
        //            logStep(25,_serialQ)
        //        });
    });
}
```

So we got the conclusion:
the key problem is that thread will be blocked while "dispatch_sync" running on current queue which is a serial queue at the same time.
main queue is also a serial queue so that it explained why you cann't call dispatch_sync in main thread