# Trouble with dispatching queues in a conditional loop

Tags: ios, objective-c, multithreading, grand-central-dispatch

```
-(void) sample
{
    dispatch_queue_t aQueue = dispatch_queue_create("hello-world", NULL);

    __block  int j=0;
    for(int i=0; i<3; ++i){
        dispatch_sync(aQueue, ^{
            j++;
            NSLog(@"I'm in Loop\n");
            if(j==2)
                dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                    NSLog(@"I'm in main for the first time\n");
                });
        });
    }
    dispatch_sync(aQueue, ^{
        NSLog(@"I'm in the second task of aQueue\n");
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            NSLog(@"I'm just about to exit from the main thread\n");
        });
    });
}
```

**Output:**

```
2016-02-02 17:11:16.226 facebookCustom Post[5078:227956] I'm in Loop
2016-02-02 17:11:16.227 facebookCustom Post[5078:227956] I'm in Loop
2016-02-02 17:11:16.227 facebookCustom Post[5078:227956] I'm in Loop
2016-02-02 17:11:16.227 facebookCustom Post[5078:227840] I'm in the second task of aQueue
2016-02-02 17:11:16.426 facebookCustom Post[5078:227840] I'm in main for the first time
2016-02-02 17:11:16.426 facebookCustom Post[5078:227840] I'm just about to exit from the main thread
```

The output of the code was pretty surprising to me since the task shouldn't be executed till the first task is completed as we have dispatched the queue the first time synchronously right? Then how could `I'm in the second task of aQueue` be printed before `I'm in main for the first time`?

Comment: @bbum One for you I think...

Comment: @originalUser2 Oh Yes! The first queue should've been deadlocked since I've dispatched both aQueue and main synchronously. Now the question is why it didn't ?
Edit: Why have you deleted your comment?

Comment: @Viki as I was initially wrong about `NSLog` being asynchronous,  it must have been because of a GCD optimisation that probably ran all of the code on the main thread anyway, therefore preventing a deadlock.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**[As already said](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35151427/2976878), this is happening because you are blocking the main thread with the `dispatch_sync` to `aQueue`and therefore your first `NSLog` to the main thread was getting postponed until after your method had finished running.**

Furthermore, your approach to this is completely wrong. Using `dispatch_sync` onto a serial queue from another serial queue is completely redundant in most cases, as the original queue will be blocked from operating until the other serial queue has finished. **It also risks creating a thread deadlock, so you should be using `dispatch_async` wherever you can.**

[As said by this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26022341/2976878), when using `dispatch_sync` from the main thread onto another serial queue, in most cases GCD will just run this on the main thread anyway, as it's expensive to transfer it.

I am however not sure what you're trying to achieve by using GCD here. The code you have is no more (if not less) efficient than running everything on the main thread (as that's what's most likely to happen behind the scenes anyway).

**If you're just trying to offload tasks onto a separate thread, then you want to be using `dispatch_async`.**

Furthermore, if you want the output to happen in a reliable order, you can use `dispatch_sync` to the main thread (*yes, I'm making an exception to my rule here, but only because it's a single `NSLog`*), thus guaranteeing that the first main thread log happens before the next (and won't cause a deadlock, because you're using `dispatch_async` onto the `aQueue`).

```
-(void) sample
{
    dispatch_queue_t aQueue = dispatch_queue_create("hello-world", DISPATCH_QUEUE_SERIAL); // I changed the attr parameter from NULL to DISPATCH_QUEUE_SERIAL for increased readability.

    __block  int j=0;
    for(int i=0; i<3; ++i){
        dispatch_async(aQueue, ^{
            j++;
            NSLog(@"I'm in Loop\n");
            if(j==2)
                dispatch_sync(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                    NSLog(@"I'm in main for the first time\n");
                });
        });
    }

    dispatch_async(aQueue, ^{
        NSLog(@"I'm in the second task of aQueue\n");
        dispatch_sync(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            NSLog(@"I'm just about to exit from the main thread\n");
        });
    });
}
```

The output is now:

```
2016-02-02 12:06:46.573 gcd test again[2351:2465744] I'm in Loop
2016-02-02 12:06:46.573 gcd test again[2351:2465744] I'm in Loop
2016-02-02 12:06:46.580 gcd test again[2351:2465707] I'm in main for the first time
2016-02-02 12:06:46.581 gcd test again[2351:2465744] I'm in Loop
2016-02-02 12:06:46.581 gcd test again[2351:2465744] I'm in the second task of aQueue
2016-02-02 12:06:46.581 gcd test again[2351:2465707] I'm just about to exit from the main thread
```

This way, the main thread can continue to run, only getting interrupted to ensure that your `NSLog` calls are getting dispatched in the correct order.

**However, I would never recommend using the main queue "*just to synchronise some calls*". In practice, you should use a separate serial queue for this.**

I hope this makes sense. GCD can be confusing even at the best of times!

Comment: But even in this case, your code could have `NSLog`ged the statements in any order but it didn't. Why?

Comment: @Viki Hmm... Yes, I was wrong about the asynchronous nature of `NSLog`. I think it was only due to the fact that you were blocking the main thread, so that the first log to the main thread was getting postponed until after the second dispatch. I have edited my answer.

Comment: another doubt.. synchronously dispatching the `aQueue` blocks the main queue until the first block(task) in `aQueue` is done or all the tasks(including the second one) of `aQueue` are done?

Comment: @Viki your entire `sample` method occurs on the main thread anyway, so GCD will first wait for that to finish before running the `dispatch_async` logs. That's why in your log, the two logs that got dispatched to the main thread appear last.

Comment: entire method? those sections where I've used `dispatch_async()` would be running on `aQueue` right?

Comment: well the `dispatch_sync` calls to `aQueue` block the main thread from running anyway, and in practice GCD will optimise this by running it all on the main thread in order to reduce the cost of transferring onto another thread.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/102364/discussion-between-viki-and-originaluser2).

Answer (score 2):

I believe this is answered more completely in the answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26020656/dispatch-sync-always-execute-block-in-main-thread) and has to do with optimisation in the GCD implementation.

Those blocks are being executed on the current (main) thread, rather than on `aQueue`, as an optimisation, and because of that any calls via `dispatch_get_main_queue()` are "queued up" (pardon the pun) to be performed later, I think in the next iteration of the run-loop.

You can get more information by logging using `NSLog()`, rather than `printf()`, as that will print the Thread ID.  Please update your question with that output.

That's about all I have for now, perhaps @bbum will swing by and clarify with a better answer.

This is a good question BTW.

Comment: You should clarify this _"Those blocks are being executed on the main thread, rather than on aQueue"_ since, this makes no sense.

Comment: I would suggest: "as an optimization, aQueue may select the current thread to execute blocks, which happens to be the main thread." Or the like.

Comment: I'm not sure that's any clearer. A better explanation can be found in the question I linked to.

Comment: I think, your answer may point to the solution to this "phenomena" - and the fact that `print` is actually asynchronous and uses "thread-confinement".

Comment: I also think there is something in the use of `printf()`, but I think it would be one thing or the other.  It would be very instructive if the OP updated their question with the output from `NSLog()`, but they have yet to do so...

Comment: This is my first ever question on SO to garner some experts attention! Thanks to you trojanfoe!

Even I would love to see what @bbum has to say, as he is the one who has initiated me to learn multi-threading and concurrency!

Are there any official Apple documentations or good links supporting what you've explained?

Comment: @Viki I got most of my information from the question I have linked, but one of those answers does provide a reference to the documentation I believe.

Answer (score 1):

Because printf isn't required to put the characters on the screen exactly at the time of the call. Each thread can collect printf output and put it on the screen when it feels like it. That is usually much more efficient.

Set a breakpoint on the printf calls, and the calls will be executed in the order you expect. printf doesn't define the order of the output when called from multiple threads.